# Unknown functions in Schwartzchild Metric

Tags: general-relativity

I was reading through MTW and they made a big deal about how we were able to make an astute choice of coordinates to eliminate unknown functions from the most general form of the metric for a spherically symmetric spacetime.

It leaves us with the following metric:

$$ ds^2 = -e^{2\Phi}dt^2 + e^{2\Lambda} dr^2 + r^2 d\Omega^2 $$

Why can't we transform away both the exponential factors to reduce it the the Minkowski metric?

From the metric transformation:

$$ g_{\mu \nu}' = \Lambda^{\rho}_{\mu '}\Lambda^{\sigma}_{\nu'} g_{\rho \sigma} $$

Can't we just make the transformation (where the $\Lambda$s aren't the same as the transformation):

$$ r \rightarrow \int dr \; e^{\Lambda (r)} $$ to eliminate the $e^{2\Lambda}$ term in the metric? And likewise for the $e^{2\Phi}$ term?

There must be something wrong with this argument as the curved space metric just reduces to the Minkowski metric in this case but I can't see why.

Comment: You can't do this to $r$ without destroying the $r^2 d\Omega$ term. The angular coordinates won't behave like angles anymore.

Comment: $\Phi$ depends on $r$, so you would have to mix together the time and radial coordinates. This generates $dr dt$ cross terms.

Comment: @knzhou Actually, when we make the transformation aren't we just changing the value of r, wouldn't the $r^2dΩ $ term still behave like normal, except with r′ instead of r?

Comment: I don't know what you mean. If you change radial coordinate to $r' = r/2$, then $r^2 d\Omega$ becomes $(2r')^2 d\Omega = 4 r'^2 d\Omega$, for example.